# Parameters of One_Wire protocol function

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microchip, programming

How can we explaine the following line of statement in mikroC PRO for PIC

```
Ow_Reset(&PORTE, 2); // Onewire reset signal
```

I understand that **`Ow_Reset`** is a predefined function used by mikroC in one wire protocol,
but I do not understand the statement **`(&PORTE,2)`**
In the **help tap** it gives the following definition of the function

```
unsigned short Ow_Reset(unsigned short *port, unsigned short pin);
```

The port name is declared as a pointer in the definition but in function call, we find the `&` operator

Comment: Do you understand what the `&` operator does in C? It is pretty well documented.

Comment: Yes, it is a bitwise AND operator, and if we apply this difinition to (&PORTE,2), we get 0b11111111 and 00000010, wich returns PIN 1 ans high and not pin 2

Comment: @learndesign Well, then that's the problem. It's not only an AND. The designers of C kept their use of special characters down to a minimum and repurposed some for other uses, depending upon the context. Try reading further about the C language. (I won't spoil the chance for you to uncover this on your own, just yet.)

Comment: @learndesign It's not an "AND" in this context, it's "address of".

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know anything about OneWire, but the `&` operator in C is used to access the address of the referenced variable. So for example if you have a variable `unsigned short PORTE`, then `&PORTE` is a pointer to `PORTE`.

So for this driver you have, you need to pass the address of `PORTE` to the function `Ow_Reset` for it to work properly. That is why the `&` is there.

This is how `&` is used as a *unary* operator in C. It’s not to be confused with `&` the binary operator, which does a bitwise AND operation.